# Commit inside a procedure?

Tags: postgresql

I have a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE parse_file(
        p_task_id integer
      ) AS $$
        DECLARE
          v_error_message text;
        BEGIN
          UPDATE file_task SET status = 'processing' WHERE task_id = p_task_id;
          COMMIT;

          -- do some inserts

          UPDATE file_task SET status = 'done' WHERE task_id = p_task_id;

          EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
              GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS v_error_message = MESSAGE_TEXT;
              UPDATE file_task SET status = 'failed', errors = ARRAY[v_error_message]
              WHERE task_id = p_task_id;
        END;
      $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Procedure parses a file and manage statuses. How can i commit after updating status to 'processing', so if other job runs and see that there is still file in process, it do nothing.

Comment: What version of postgres, and how are you invoking the procedure? [The docs note](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html) that you must use `CALL` or `DO` to be able to do transaction control in a procedure; if the top-level statement is a SELECT, it won't work.

Comment: @AdamKG pg 12.0, invoking with CALL, but got {cannot commit while a subtransaction is active}

Comment: You are going to have to show how you are using this procedure with 'other job'.

Comment: @adrian-klaver it's just a js function that runs every minute, and check if there is some pending task in the queue and no other task is running by checking status !== 'processing'

Comment: Alright but what is the sequence you use to get to the CALL of the procedure. I suspect you are running afoul of this ```"But if the call stack is CALL proc1() → SELECT func2() → CALL proc3(), then the last procedure cannot do transaction control, because of the SELECT in between."``` from here:https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html.

Comment: It sounds like there's already a transaction open when you are calling your procedure.  At a higher level, perhaps `SELECT FOR UPDATE` would be better than changing the status?